# Symfony - Deserialize entity that contains ManyToOne property

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I have a Entity "Eleve" :

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

/**
* @ORM\Entity
* @ORM\Table()
*/
class Eleve
{

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * 
 * @Serializer\Groups({"get"})
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 * 
 * @Serializer\Groups({"get"})
 */
private $nom;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 * 
 * @Serializer\Groups({"get"})
 */
private $prenom;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Promotion", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="promotion_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * 
 * @Serializer\Groups({"promos"})
 */
private $promotion;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="NoteModule", mappedBy="module", cascade={"persist"})
 * 
 * @Serializer\Groups({"notes"})
 */
private $notes;


public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getNom()
{
    return $this->nom;
}

public function setNom($nom)
{
    $this->nom = $nom;

    return $this;
}

public function getPrenom()
{
    return $this->prenom;
}

public function setPrenom($prenom)
{
    $this->prenom = $prenom;

    return $this;
}

public function getPromotion()
{
    return $this->promotion;
}

public function setPromotion($promotion)
{
    $this->promotion = $promotion;

    return $this;
}

public function getNotes()
{
    return $this->notes;
}

public function setNotes($notes)
{
    $this->notes = $notes;

    return $this;
}
}
```

And "Eleve" entity is joined to "Promotion":

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use JMS\Serializer\Annotation as Serializer;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table()
 */
class Promotion
{

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 * 
 * @Serializer\Groups({"get"})
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
 * 
 * @Serializer\Groups({"get"})
 */
private $title;

/** 
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer") 
 * 
 * @Serializer\Groups({"get"})
 */
private $annee;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Formation", cascade={"all"}, fetch="EAGER")
 * 
 * @Serializer\Groups({"formations"})
 */
private $formation;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Eleve", mappedBy="promotion", cascade={"persist"})
 * 
 * @Serializer\Groups({"eleves"})
 */
private $eleves;


public function getId()
{
    return $this->id;
}

public function getTitle()
{
    return $this->title;
}

public function setTitle($title)
{
    $this->title = $title;

    return $this;
}

public function getAnnee()
{
    return $this->annee;
}

public function setAnnee($annee)
{
    $this->annee = $annee;

    return $this;
}

public function getFormation()
{
    return $this->formation;
}

public function setFormation($formation)
{
    $this->formation = $formation;

    return $this;
}

public function getEleves()
{
    return $this->eleves;
}

public function setEleves($eleves)
{
    $this->eleves = $eleves;

    return $this;
}
}
```

And when i want to send this Json file by Http Post:

```
[
    {
        "nom":"EleveName",
        "prenom":"EleveFirstName",
        "promotion":1
    }
]
```

I have the following error :

> "message": "Invalid data \"1\"(integer), expected \"AppBundle\Entity\Promotion\".",

I think this mean that he want a "Promotion" entity instead of an integer.
Is it possible to only give promotion id like i did in the json or am i forced to pass the entire entity ?

I use FosRestBundle to do my http request, and i use Doctrine for database.
I don't really know how to deal with this issue, i didn't find anything about it on net. Maybe you know where i can search to help me.

Does anyone can help me ?

Thanks !